# Display ngx bootstrap tooltip when mouse entered or hovered and remove when either clicked on mouse removed from there

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngx-bootstrap

I dont fully understand the concept of what triggers exactly do for https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#triggers-custom

For example, when we do:

```
triggers="mouseenter:click"
```

Does it mean that tooltip will be displayed when we hover/put the mouse there and disappear when clicked?

If so, is it possible to specify two events for which tooltip should disappear.

Example, I want to display the tooltip when I hover on it and then make it disappear either when I click on it or remove the mouse from there. Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you ever figured it out?

Comment: The answer from Nikola worked for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an array of events, something like this might work: `triggers="mouseenter mouseleave click"`

> **triggers** => Specifies events that should trigger. Supports a space separated list of event names.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer of @Nikola Gavric doesn't solve a problem in that: `mouseenter` (show tooltip) > `click` (hide tooltip) > `mouseleave` (show tooltip again).

For ones who need a trigger like on the Gmail's action menu (showing tooltip when mouse hovers and dispearing it when mouse leaves or clicked), use below:

```
triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave mouseenter:click"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may play with both of [Custom triggers](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#triggers-custom) and [Manual triggering](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#triggers-manual):

```
<button 
  tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
  triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
  #pop="bs-tooltip"
  (click)="pop.hide()"
>Tooltip</button>
```

This code would not fire the tooltip by the click when it is hidden. The same result is when you apply `triggers="mouseenter click:mouseleave click"` with no `(click)`, but it looks hacky... maybe it is a bug, but `triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave click"` does not give such a result. Anyway, handling `(click)` manually, you are getting a relative flexibility.